# Stuck on finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors of 3x3 matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Im trying to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\1& 1 & 1\\0 &1 &1\end{bmatrix}$

so far I worked out:

$A-λI=\begin{bmatrix}1-λ & 1 & 0\\1& 1-λ & 1\\0 &1 &1-λ\end{bmatrix}$

I know you have to calculate the determinant but im not exactly sure how to do it.

It is also asking me to Show that if the eigenvectors of A, {u1,u2,u3}, are normalized to unit length then they form an orthonormal set, i.e. uTi uj = δij where δij = 1 if i = j and δij = 0 if i ̸= j. Hence write A in the form A = UΛUT where Λ is a diagonal matrix and UT U = I3.

Please help.

Comment: Look here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion

Comment: To show that the eigenvectors are pairwise orthogonal, it is sufficient to show that there are no multiple roots of the characteristic polynomial (which is the case here) because the eigenvectors to different eigenvalues are always orthogonal.

Comment: @Peter I don't get it sorry Im not very familiar with this just started.

Comment: Yes I know that

Comment: yes I Know that

Comment: If the eigenvalues are pairwise different, there is an eigenvector for each eigenvalue. If you put them together, you get the matrix you need to DIAGONALIZE the given matrix $A$, that means you have a matrix $T$ with $T^{-1}AT=D$, where $D$ is a diagonal-matrix containing the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: I still don't get it

Comment: We should delete unnecessary posts, then please explain what is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve:

$\det\left(A-λI\right)=\det \left(\begin{bmatrix}1-λ & 1 & 0\\1& 1-λ & 1\\0 &1 &1-λ\end{bmatrix}\right) \overset{!}{=} 0$

In order to calculate the determinant, I suggest you use Sarrus's rule [Sarrus's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).
The resulting polynomial

$(1-\lambda)^3 -2\,(1-\lambda) = (1-\lambda)\,(\lambda^2-2\lambda +1)\overset{!}{=} 0 $.

You should be able to take it from here on.

You will end up with three Eigenvalues. The corresponding eigenvectors can be obtained, finding a solution to

$ (A-\lambda_i)\, v_i \overset{!}{=} 0 $, for $i = 1,2,3$.

Note that your matrix $A$ is a symmetric matrix.
Let $v_1,v_2$ be eigenvectors to a symmetric matrix $A$ with non-ientical eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ Than:

$\lambda_1\,v_1^T\,v_2 = (A\,v_1)^T\,v_2 = v_1^T\,A^T\,v_2  \overset{A=A^T}{=} v_1^T(A\,v_2) = \lambda_2 \, v_1^T\, v_2$

and thus
$(\lambda_1 -\lambda_2)v_1^T\, v_2 = 0$.

Given $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$, follows that $v_1^T\,v_2 = 0$, which is the definition of orthogonality.

Summing up: 
A symmetric, real matrix $A$

- (has only real eigenvalues)
- It's eigenvectors to corresponding, non-identical eigenvalues, are orthogonal

Comment: So how about where it says Write A in the form A = UΛUT where Λ is a diagonal matrix and UT U = I3, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You can calculate the determinant developing by the first row:
$$
\det
\begin {bmatrix}
1-\lambda&1&0\\
1&1-\lambda&1\\
0&1&1-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}=
(1-\lambda)\left(\det\begin {bmatrix}
1-\lambda&1\\
1&1-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}\right)-1\left( \det
\begin {bmatrix}
1&1\\
0&1-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}\right)=(1-\lambda)\left[(1-\lambda)^2-1\right]-(1-\lambda)=
(1-\lambda)(\lambda^2-2\lambda-1)
$$
so you find the eigenvalues:
$$
\lambda_1=1 \qquad \lambda_2=1+\sqrt{2} \qquad \lambda_3=1-\sqrt{2 }
$$
Now, solving the linear equations:
$$
\begin {bmatrix}
1&1&0\\
1&1&1\\
0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin {bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end {bmatrix}=\lambda_i\begin {bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end {bmatrix}
$$
you can find the eigenvectors corresponding to each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.

E.g., for $\lambda_1=1$ you have:
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y=x\\
x+y+z=y\\
y+z=z
\end{cases}
$$
So the eigenspace is given by the vectors with $y=0$ and $x=-z$ and you can chose as an eigenvector $u_1=[-1,0,1]^T$.

In the some way you can find the eigenvectors for $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ and find: $u_2=[1,\sqrt{2},1]^T$,$u_3=[1,-\sqrt{2},1]^T$.

Since they are eigenvectors of different eigenvalues they are are orthogonal (you can verify this calculating the inner product) and you can normalize dividing by the modulus.

Finally: the matrix $\Lambda$ has as diagonal elements the eigenvalues and the matrix $U$ has as columns the corresponding eigenvectors.

You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#How_to_diagonalize_a_matrix) for an other example.

Comment: Can you help me find the eigenvectors for this example and I will work on other ones as Im not exactly sure.

Comment: I've add something to my  answer. I hope it can be helpful.

Comment: Is u2 and u3 the eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes. $u_2$ is an eigenvector of $\lambda_2=1+\sqrt{2}$ and  $u_3$ is an eigenvector of $\lambda_3=1-\sqrt{2}$